# UDP Port Scan Attack from a previously used IP address

Tags: network, attacks, ip, router, udp

Yesterday my internet connection is interrupted and I checked the logs. In logs, I saw 2 UDP Port Scan Attack happened a week ago. After a little bit of research, I convinced myself that it is common but after deeply looking through the logs, I see that both of the attack comes from similar as my previous public IP. By 'previous' I mean it seems within the IP range of my previous internet subscription of same ISP which I had used in another city, then terminated 2 years ago. (Checked it from some previous login notifications in my email and first 2 parts (blocks) are exact same, last 2 part are different) I am currently using same ISP in a different city and within completely different range and this subscription is just 5 months old. There is almost 2 years gap between subscriptions.

Destination IP is my WAN IP, this is different from my public IP but I find out that my connection is behind CGNAT.

So log seems like this: DATE kern.alert kernel: UDP PORT SCAN ATTACK:IN='XXXX' OUT= SRC='IP within same range with old IPs' DST='my WAN IP' and goes with other things like ports, etc.

When I check the source ports, one of them seems belongs to custom backup system in tcp section and 'reserved' in udp section, and the other one seems sna-cs service in both tcp and udp which I don't know what it is. I couldn't find any information about destination ports.

So, I feel like I am clearly targeted by someone who knows my previous and current IP's.
Qs:

- How can I know if this attack blocked or not?
- Is this some kind of IP spoofing? I am not that technically competent but as I get from other cases, this seems relevant.
- I had some accounts compromised years ago, last week I tried to claim one of them and account suspended immediately after I reset the password. I assume someone got in to that account before and added some backup email or something, with that it has previous and current IPs. (I can't confirm this because I can't get into account since it's suspended) How likely this is? Does IP spoofing and this seems relevant?
- Also on all accounts have my public IP, not WAN IP, could someone knows my public IP find my WAN IP? Or attack made to public IP and just router shows it as my WAN IP?

EDIT: I removed irrelevant parts and updated new information.

Comment: someone scanning you from the same ip block you used previously could simply be explained by them scanning you from within the same broader network (ie. your isp) ; to conclude that someone is performing some longitudinal attack on you is a bit of a leap (btw. i'm not saying it's impossible) - please edit your q to clarify the following:  1) did your account theft occur around the same time as you switched isp?  2) were any of the accounts your account with the isp?  3) have you checked that you're not paying for two accounts with your isp?

Comment: re: duplicate - it's customary to ensure only one copy of your q at a given time, but it would be polite to link to it - if you're other q was asked previously and has "fallen quiet" then i see no problem with you asking again here in a different forum ; however, if it's actively being answered over at superuser then you should probably edit this q to put the link in and then close it here

Comment: @brynk 1 - i dont know the exact time of it, it's a throwaway account, it's been a long time since i signed to it, i just know i logged in to it when i had that subscription. btw between switching isps there's 2 years of gap, i haven't subscription in that 2 years of gap. 2 - i don't get this one. 3 - of course. i terminated previous one, switched cities and 2 years after i got new subscription.

Comment: @brynk actually here it seems more relevant, so is it ok to put link to it which is on superuser to redirect people here? i don't know which one would be better for the context

Comment: yep either way, it's best to only have one instance of your q on the network at any given time (my point is if you act now before a mod does the decision will be yours);  ok so you closed your other account which eliminates the possibility that someone else is still using it - are you still using the same devices that you were using previously?

Comment: *"I feel like I am clearly targeted by someone who knows my previous and current IP'"* - I don't think that this is the only interpretation of what you see nor that it is the most likely interpretation. Unfortunately we mainly have your interpretation of things here, i.e. neither the exact information before your interpretation nor anything which your did not consider relevant but which might be. It is easy to pick the things which fit the kind of interpretation one already has and ignore anything else.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You are right but I thought it because of my account's compromised. Btw it turns out my ISP is using something called cgn and dest IP is almost same with my wan ip. So does this mean attack targeted all users within this block not specifially me?

Comment: this q will benefit from an edit to improve focus and remove information that is no longer relevant - have a think about what you actually want an answer to: is it the incorrect udp src and dst, and whether it was blocked? (this is a networking q) is it the possibility that someone is targetting you specifically over multiple years? (as @SteffenUllrich said, highly unlikely) .. also, the q "what can i do to become more secure" is way too broad to be answered, but already has many answers here if you do a bit of digging around

Comment: @mzt: There is too few information but I doubt there is a relevant attack in the first place and even less one targeted you. Unfortunately some SoHo routers tend to call everything which is not supposed to be there (i.e. matching outgoing connections) an "attack" - and then brag how many of these they have blocked. In most cases this is just noise you don't need to worry about. Unfortunately the routers don't help you with finding out what really would be relevant and instead needlessly scare you. What you should worry about instead are the things not reported by the router :(

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for boosting my level of anxiety with 'attacks not reported by router'. :) I hope it is some kind of harmless thing like you said but one thing made me too nervous about this is it comes from similar ip to my previous ip, my concern with this is it could be some kind of identity spoofing, that's what made me worried.

Comment: @brynk I edited it with the new information.

Comment: @mzt: everything which your router reports as "attack blocked" is blocked - even if it was no attack relevant in your environment or no attack at all. The real danger comes not from somebody scanning your network from outside, but from you "inviting" the attacker from inside, i.e. opening phishing mails to steal credentials, mails with malware attachments,  surfing the internet and stumbling over malwaretisment, downloading stuff from the internet ... . Your simple router will not protect against any of this since it has no visibility into this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich oh ok, I thought you're mentioning about something else and yes, I wasnt paying too much attention to it since they were my throwaway and not important accounts which has no important information but you are obviously right. after I realize it I became too anxious and with a limited information I am connecting all dots in illogical ways sometime.